# Xcode IB - Resizable image on UIButton

Tags: ios, xcode, image, uibutton, interface-builder

Is there a way to assign a stretchable image to a UIButton from Xcode's Interface Builder? and not from code? I mean, to set an image and stretch it only on certain parts (like 9-patch for android)

I am using the properties of image, and background and the stretching section of the view but nothing seems to work to stretch the image on the edges I place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes**, I think what you are looking for is slicing. In the asset catalog, when you select an image, on the bottom right corner you can find the **Show Slicing** button. When you click this button Xcode will display the slicing editor. By using it, you can define which parts of an image should stretch and which should stay unchanged.

The editor should display something like this.

[image: slicing editor preview]

You can find another example [here](http://beckyhansmeyer.com/2016/03/08/resizable-button-backgrounds-in-xcode/)